# Network Error when wanting to modify a ACL Role

Tags: permissions

I get a "Network Error" when I want to modify an ACL Role.

This happens on my Production Site which is in https, and not on 2 other test sites which are in http.

All my sites are in Civi 4.7.2 / Drupal 7.42

Comment: Same problem when I want to modify a custom field

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the question : this problem was due to errors in my .htaccess file.
Once fxed, everything works OK.

Question closed.

Comment: could you post your fix here as an answer , it will help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to force https://www.xxx ; To do this, I modified .htaccess :

Addd 3 lines starting from 65 :
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Uncommented 3 lines arround 95 :
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

(Don't ask me why : I don't know anything to this : a friend of mine just told me)